# Why using named pipes gives random chars in C?

Tags: c, pipe

I'm using the `mkfifo` command in Linux.
This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>  // mkfifo
#include <sys/stat.h>   // mkfifo
#include <fcntl.h>      // O_WRONLY
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char* filename = "myf";
    int res = mkfifo(filename, 0777); 
    pid_t x = fork();
    if(x){
        char buff[4];
        res = open("myf", O_RDONLY);
        if(res == -1){
            printf("problem opening fifo\n");
        }
        while(read(res, buff, 4)){
            printf("Father:  %s\n", buff);
        }
    }
    else{
        int toFath = open (filename, O_WRONLY);
        char buff [4];
        strcpy(buff, "hi");
        write(toFath, buff, strlen(buff));
        strcpy(buff, "bye");
        write(toFath, buff, strlen(buff));
        close(toFath);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But it prints:

```
Father:  hi@
Father:  bye
```

I don't understand why there are these char that I didn't write (@). I know `strcpy` copies the string with a null terminator so when the father prints it should stop at the null terminator so why isn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

strlen(buff) returns 3, therefore write() will output the first 3 bytes of buff

Comment: Consider [edit]ing this answer to explain *why* `strlen(buff)` returns 3.

Comment: No.  Given `strcpy(buff, "hi");`, `strlen( buff )` returns 2, not 3.

Answer (score 0):

the first `char buff[4]` is not initialized. As a result, the `read(res, buff, 4)` might return a buff that is not '\0' terminated.

A fix, initializing the first buff with this `char buff[4] = {0}`.